# How to add page transition to Iron Router using ccorcos:transitioner

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm Meteor beginner, and I'm trying to build simple survey website, which i already completed everything, but i want to add some effect to make it looks fancy, which is page transition. I already added the package, here is my code in .js file, in client folder:

```
//Transition
Transitioner.default({
    fromRoute: '/',
    toRoute: '/home',
    velocityAnimation: {
        in: 'transition.fadeIn',
        out: 'transition.fadeOut'
    }
})

//Inside HTML file
<template name="AppLayout">
    {{#transitioner}}
        {{>yield}}
    {{/transitioner}}
</template>
```

the error i got from console is:

```
velocityAnimation must contain a velocityAnimation.in
```

As i read the Getting Started from [https://github.com/ccorcos/meteor-transitioner], i don't really understand much,so how do i make this page transition works, thanks very much and sorry if i got some terminology wrong here and made some misunderstanding.